# Remove style when calling Page ID

Tags: php, wordpress, css

I'm trying to call a page ID without it altering the css properties of the current template.

Calling a Page ID works but I believe it takes on the properties of that template? As the product-image div disappears off the page?!
The code I have at the moment is below.

PHP

```
  <div class="entry">

    <div class="product-list">
        <?php 
        $id=7; 
        $post = get_page($id); 
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
        echo $content;  
        ?>
      </div>
      <div class="product-content">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
      </div> 

      <div class="product-image"><?php the_post_thumbnail();?></div>

    </div><!-- / .entry -->


</div>
```

When entering a paragraph tag in the product-list class the layout works perfectly.

Anyone have any idea on how to remove the complete style of the page or if this is not the issue, what it could be? Thank you!

TRIED - but didn't work

```
  <div class="entry">

    <div class="product-list">
        <?php 
                    $id=7; 
                    $post = get_page($id); 
                    //remove auto p filter
                    remove_filter ('the_content','wpautop');
                    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
                    //return the filter for other posts/pages down the road
                    add_filter ('the_content','wpautop');
                    echo $content;  
                    ?>
      </div>
      <div class="product-content">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
      </div> 

      <div class="product-image"><?php the_post_thumbnail();?></div>

    </div><!-- / .entry -->


</div>
```

Comment: I think you need to inform what cms you're using, I assume it's wordpress? then you may need to add 'wordpress' tag, so any wordpress expert can find your question.

Comment: Yes, it is wordpress sorry.

Comment: im having a hard time understanding your question

Comment: @mark, essentially I am trying to create a submenu and call the content from a different page and bring it into a new template. A page called "products" has two product names in the content area. I then created a page for each product name using the template php code as shown above. I believe I may need to look at a differently and try to insert a "sub_menu" code into the 'project-list' div. Thanks for looking anyway.

Comment: Is this customized code on a new page-name.php template? It might be easier to begin a new custom page template than conditionally load all this new stuff?